# ReactJS scroll event listener - "infinite scroll"

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

sorry for my English. I'm trying to make an "infinite Scroll" with an api that sends me some data. It's easy for me to make that working if I use a button with an "handleClick" that adds the new data from de API, but it's impossible for me to use the same "handleClick" when the "scroll is at the bottom".EVENT.

this is my handleClick:

```
 const handleClick = () => {
    if (peopleNext) {
      setPeople([...people, ...peopleNext]);
    }
    setPeopleNext(null);

    if (dataNext) {
      axios
        .get(dataNext)

        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data.data.results);
          setPeopleNext(data.data.results);
          if (data.data.next) {
            setDataNext(data.data.next);
          } else {
            setDataNext(null);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  };
```

I take the position correctly and get a "This is the bottom" in the console. But some errors appear when I try to apply the "handleClick" at the same moment.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks!!

this is the useEffect i´m working to get the position.

```
useEffect(() => {
    function updatePosition() {
        if(window.scrollY + document.documentElement.clientHeight === document.documentElement.scrollHeight){
        handleClick()
      } 
    }
   
    window.addEventListener("scroll", updatePosition);
    updatePosition();

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", updatePosition);
  }, []);
```